# How can I set the console font to Raster Font 12x8 in C++?

Tags: c++, fonts, console

I want to set the console font to the 12x8 raster font programmatically in C++.
I'm currently using `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` and the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` struct.
However, when I set the font face to `Terminal` and the font size to 12x8, I get the 12x5 font instead.

Here is the code:

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
fontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(fontInfo);
fontInfo.dwFontSize.X = 8;
fontInfo.dwFontSize.Y = 12;
wcscpy_s(fontInfo.FaceName, L"Terminal");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &fontInfo);
```

The font I want to use:

[image]

The font I get:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before or does anyone know how to solve it?
Let me know if you need more detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Added the code. @jsp